# C++ memory leak using float 2d array, disappears if I use double

Tags: c++

I am writing in C++ using Visual Studio 2013. I have noticed an abnormality with the following simple code (found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7459/)):

```
const int HEIGHT = 1000;
const int WIDTH = 100000;
double **p2DArray;

// Allocate memory
p2DArray = new double*[HEIGHT];
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
    p2DArray[i] = new double[WIDTH];

// De-Allocate memory to prevent memory leak
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
    delete[] p2DArray[i];
delete[] p2DArray;

return 0;
```

When I put a breakpoint on "return 0", using Windows' Task Manager, I can see that the application's "Memory" footprint is 0.3 MB. However, if I substitute "double" with "float" or "int", I get "31.3 MB". Furthermore, by modifying HEIGHT/WIDTH, I get different number of MBs for **int** and **float** while the number for **double** remains the same - 0.3 MB. Could someone offer an explanation?

Thanks.

P.S. I need to use raw pointers because of a library function.

Comment: `delete` and friends release the memory to the C++ runtime; whether the runtime then releases the memory back to the operating system, causing the memory numbers you see in Task Manager to decrease, is up to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a debug report about memory leaks pretty easiliy, e.g. using [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Your code does not produce a leak with neither `float` nor `double`, it's perfectly fine. In practice, you should not rely on the numbers the task manager gives you. They are at best a coarse approximation, and just because you called `delete` it doesn't mean that memory is *instantly* given back to the OS.